# How to format elements accessed from a many to many relationship?

Tags: python, django

I'm sorry for the noob question, I just started learning Django..

I have a manytomany relationship in a model, and I'm trying to format the output of that model to include all the elements in the many to many relationship.

I figured out how to access them, as just using self.toppings resulted in orders.Toppings.none.

Now I have a query set returned. I'm assuming I have to iterate over the items in the query set to format the string, but I'm not sure how to do that and also return the string, unless I should store the data in a new list prior to retuning.. I tried this, and it's just returning as a list, but I don't want it to be formatted as a list, do I need to iterate inside of the return line to do that?

Here's my code for context:

```
class CreatedItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="createdItem")
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item} with {self.toppings.all()}"
```

It's currently formatting as:

```
<QuerySet [<Topping: Ham>, <Topping: Sausage>]>
```

But I'd like it just to format as "Ham, Sausage"

Do I need to use a for loop inside the return statement?

Comment: Yes, you have to. But why do you need it this way?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `value_list` to get the corresponding need fields value. But first we see why we are getting this response.

Say we have two models like

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

We are adding data to Publication Model

```
>>> p1 = Publication(title='The Python Journal')
>>> p1.save()
>>> p2 = Publication(title='Science News')
>>> p2.save()
>>> p3 = Publication(title='Science Weekly')
>>> p3.save()
>>> p4 = Publication(title='The Python Journal')
>>> p4.save()
```

and Also in Article Models as like

```
>>> a1 = Article(headline='NASA uses Python')
>>> a1.save()
>>> a1.publications.add(p1, p2)
>>> a1.publications.add(p3, p4)
```

Now if we want to get corresponding results of a1's publication we will get as like

```
>>> a1.publications.all()
<QuerySet [<Publication: Highlights for Children>, <Publication: Science News>, <Publication: Science Weekly>, <Publication: The Python Journal>]>
```

Why we are actually getting this response ? this is for we add `__str__` defination of our Publication as such ..

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

But if we want just `publication__title` in our Article reponse, we can do this by

```
>>> Article.objects.values_list('publications__title').get(pk=a1)
>>> <QuerySet [(Highlights for Children), (Science News), (Science Weekly), (The Python Journal)]>
```

Hope this will help to understand.